# In my React app, why does "setPointerCapture" not work if I am changing the z-index of my (draggable) component (that is using "setPointerCapture")?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have discovered a very strange, undesired behavior of my React application that I would like to understand and to correct.

Unfortunately, my application is quite large and I was not able to recreate the issue I am encountering in a smaller application (for demonstration purposes), although I really did try.

**Here is what I would like to achieve:**
In order to control re-rendering of all my visual content represented by data, I use useRef hooks in a couple of custom hooks to represent and manipulate my data without triggering a re-render due to a changed state. Once all my data is “up-to-date” (or once it makes sense from by “business logic’s perspective”) I call `requestUpdate` in my main component that updates the relevant data represented by useState hooks. This data goes as props into all my components.
Now, I would like to perform a drag-and-drop operation on some visual components. In order to catch all relevant events, I call `setPointerCapture` on receiving an `onPointerDown` event. In order to properly see the components I am dragging around I adjust their z-indices in order to have the components being dragged “on top”. That works fine, by the way.

**Here is the issue that I am encountering:**
What does not work is the `setPointerCapture` if I change the z-indices. Strangely, if I comment out the respective little part of my code that changes the z-indices, everything works fine. If I don’t (i.e., if I leave these lines in my code), my component never “gets” to “capture the pointer” (I am sure since I observed that the “onGotPointerCapture” event is never fired). The consequence is that I “loose” my element if I am dragging to fast and if the mouse arrow is no longer over my component (which is exactly what I wanted to avoid in the first place with my `setPointerCapture`).

Please find below the relevant extracts of my code.

This is where I (try to) do my `setPointerCapture`. This function handles the `onPointerDown` event "fired" by the visual component that I would like to drag.

```tsx
const onPointerDown = useCallback(
    (event: React.PointerEvent) => {
      // Case 1: We are neither allowed to drag nor to select
      if (!draggingEnabled && !selectingEnabled) return;
      // ...
      // Case 2: We are allowed to drag (and we will select before we actually start dragging)
      if (draggingEnabled) {
        const target: HTMLDivElement = event.target as HTMLDivElement;
        target.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
        // ...
        onStartDragging(id, event.shiftKey);
        return;
      }
      // Case 3: We are "only" allowed to select
      // ...
    },
    [id, draggingEnabled, selectingEnabled, onSelect, onStartDragging]
  );
```

This is the interface defining the props that are used by my visual component that I would like to drag. The relevant property is, obviously, the `zIndex`.

```ts
export interface VisualDiagramElementData {
  id: string;
  top: number;
  left: number;
  height: number;
  width: number;
  // ...
  zIndex: number;
  // ...
}
```

Here my `elements` are declared using a useRef hook.

```tsx
  const elements: VisualDiagramElementData[] = useRef<
    VisualDiagramElementData[]
  >(
    initialDiagramElements.map((element: DiagramElement) => ({
      id: element.id,
      top: element.top,
      left: element.left,
      height: element.height,
      width: element.width,
      // ...
      zIndex: element.zIndex,
      // ...
    }))
  ).current;
```

This is the critical function. It handles the `elements` that are represented by my visual components that I would like to drag. `elements` uses the useRef hook (see above).

```tsx
const onStartDragging = useCallback(
    (id: string, shiftKeyPressed: boolean) => {
      // We want to drag or to select. Select element with current id if not yet selected
      // ...

      // Adjust order of elements to ensure that dragged elememts are (and remain after dragging) on top
      // If I comment this out from here ...
      const sortedElements: VisualDiagramElementData[] = elements.sort(
        (elementA, elementB) => {
          if (elementA.selected && !elementB.selected) return 1;
          if (!elementA.selected && elementB.selected) return -1;
          return 0;
        }
      );

      for (let i = 0; i < sortedElements.length; i++) {
        sortedElements[i].zIndex = i + 1;
      }
      // ... to here, there is no issue any more!

      requestUpdate();
    },
    [elements, isSelected, requestUpdate]
  );
```

`requestUpdate()` updates the data (represented by an array using a useState hook) that is going as props into the component I would like to drag. `auxElements` are the "elements" from my useRef hook, i.e., the `elements` in the code above.

```tsx
// useRef hooks
  const requestUpdate = useRef(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      setElements([...auxElements]);
      // ...
    });
  }).current;

  // useState hooks
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<VisualDiagramElementData[]>([]);
```